# Passing aws access keys from another file to Ansible dynamic inventory file

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-inventory

I am trying to pass aws credentials to dynamic inventory file from another file.

The dynamic inventory file `aws_ec2.yaml` contains (fake keys):

```yaml
---
plugin: aws_ec2

aws_access_key: lksldeireorierbnebrirhireri
aws_secret_key: zeueze7er76

regions:
  - us-west-2
```

I don't want to use my keys here. Even I don't want to use `aws_profile`. Rather I want to create a seperate file with my credentials. Suppose, My credential file `key.yaml` contains:

```yaml
my_access_key: lksldeireorierbnebrirhireri
my_secret_key: zeueze7er76
```

I am able to pass these keys to playbook by `ansible-playbook -e @key.yaml my_playbook.yaml`.
How I can pass these key in my dynamic inventory file `aws_ec2.yaml`? It can be by passing extra vars or vault or environment variable.

Comment: Cant these just go in your `.aws/shared_credentials` file and be picked automatically?

Comment: This will happen when I use aws cli and aws_profile. As I mentioned i didn't want that.

Comment: The documentation states you can set [`use_extra_vars`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/aws_ec2_inventory.html#parameter-use_extra_vars). Did you try it? It should let you use your variables inside the plugin configuration file.

Comment: I am not sure how should I proceed. Can you please show a demonstration?